# Class "PDO" not found in Cpanel

Tags: laravel, pdo

I'm encountering an issue on Cpanel, and I'd like to ask, even though I've enabled PDO extensions,

I'm still getting the error 'Class "PDO" not found.' I've tried various methods and searched for a lot of documentation, but it's still not working. Below are screenshots of my Cpanel and my php.ini. I greatly appreciate your assistance. I am using `Laravel 10` and `PHP 8.2.`

[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFG9C.png)
[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUBOO.png)
[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id64i.png)

Comment: Did you import PDO class in your file? add `use PDO;` after your namespace